# Верстка не стандартного блока с бордером

Tags: html, css

https://prnt.sc/p3axx5

Есть вот такой блок, как можно сверстать так, чтобы бордер не был виден под машиной?

У меня получилось вот так: https://prnt.sc/p3ayc3
Но это не совсем то, что нужно

Comment: Ты лучше верстку покажи...

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.car {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="outer">
    <svg width="160px" height="150px">
         <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="orange" 
         stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="100 180 "/>
         <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="orange" 
         stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="135 80 "/>
       </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>
      <span>Karamba</span><br> <span>auto</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="car">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryENP.png" alt="car">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

задать изображению автомобилю position:absolute; bottom: -20px; right: -50px; z-index:3 (или просто выше чем у родителей и соседей) относительно родительского блока